# Java errors about variable

Tags: java

I create a program to calculate the tuition. I almost finish it, but there are some errors. I don't know why it's wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Tuition {
   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      int hour = getHours();
      char major = getMajor();
      char status =  getStatus();
      displayTuition();
   }
   public static int getHours() {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("How many credit hours did you take:");
      int hour = kb.nextInt();
      if (hour >= 12) {
      int tuitionfee = 800;
    } else {
      tutionfee = 70*hour;
      }   
   return hour;
   }

   public static char getMajor() {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("What's your major?");
      char major = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
      if (major == 'C'||major == 'c') {
      System.out.println("Computer Science");
      int labfee = 25;
      } else if (major == 'O'||major == 'o') {
      System.out.println("Other Science");
      int labfee = 35;
      } else if (major == 'X'||major == 'x') {
      System.out.println("Non-Science");
      int labfee = 0;
      }
   return major;

   }
   public static char getStatus() {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("You are in state student or not(yes for Y/y,no for N/n)");
   char state = kb.nextLine().charAt(0);
   if (state == 'Y'||state == 'y') {
      System.out.println("In State");
      int statusfee = 5;
   } else if (state == 'N'||state == 'n') {
      System.out.println("Out-of-State");
      int statusfee = 5+20%(hour+labfee);
   } else {
      System.out.print("FALSE");
     }
   return state;
   }

   public static void displayTuition() {
   System.out.println("Credit Hours:" +int hour);
   System.out.println("Major:" +char major);
   System.out.println("Residencey" +char state);
   } 
}
```

The wrong part is

```
public static void displayTuition() {
   System.out.println("Credit Hours:" +int hour);
   System.out.println("Major:" +char major);
   System.out.println("Residencey" +char state);
   }
```

For that way, java says"Tuition.java:56: error: '.class' expected" and "Tuition.java:56: error: ';' expected".
Then I tried:

```
public static void displayTuition() {
       System.out.println("Credit Hours:" + hour);
       System.out.println("Major:" + major);
       System.out.println("Residencey" + state);
       }
```

but it's still wrong, I remember I did something like this which is right.
For that way, java says "symbol:   variable hour".

Comment: What do you mean by "it is wrong"? Please give us something to go on. **What** is wrong? **How** is it wrong? What is it supposed to be doing? Please improve this question. Also, please fix your title. `"About a program"` tells us nothing of use. You should summarize your actual problem in the title, similar to a newspaper headline. Make it informative.

Comment: You are declaring local variables which are limited in scope to each method.  Most likely you intended to either use fields, or pass the values as arguments. BTW Your IDE should have an auto-fix for this.

Comment: Does `else {
      tutionfee = 70*hour;
      } ` not give you compilation error? Surely `tutionfee` has to be out of scope.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the method `displayTuition` you are using three variables that aren't in scope. While they *are* declared in `main` (which calls `displayTuition()`), the method doesn't "know" about them. For them to be in scope, they need to be passed in as parameters to the `displayTuition()` method (simplest solution). Like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    int hour = getHours();
    char major = getMajor();
    char status =  getStatus();
    displayTuition(hour, major, status);
}

// other methods
...


public static displayTuition(int hour, char major, char status) {
    System.out.println("Credit Hours:" + hour);
    //etc
}
```

The harder (but better, IMO) option is that you could restructure the `Tuition` class so that it has these private data members, and move the static methods into it. Then, the main function could create a Tuition object and call the relevant methods on it.

Something like this:

```
public class Tuition {
   private int hour;
   private char major;
   private char status;

   public Tuition(Scanner kb) {
       // Initialize variables using methods that were initially static
       this.hour = this.getHours(kb); //Pass in the scanner, since you use it all over the place.
       ...
   }

   public static void main (String[] args) {
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
       Tuition tuition = new Tuition();
       tuition.displayTuition();
   }

   public int getHours(Scanner kb) {
       // Do the processing you have written
   }
   // other methods for major and status

   public void displayTuition() {
       System.out.println("Credit Hours:" + this.hour);
       // etc
   }
   ...
}
```

This way, your code becomes easier to understand, and you are able to avoid duplication.

Comment: I did the simplest solution like you posted.
Tuition.java:8: error: method displayTuition in class Tuition cannot be applied to given types;
      displayTuition(hour, major, status);
      ^
  required: no arguments
  found: int,char,char
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

and it still have variable problem.

Comment: I hit submit before I was finished. Try again. I tried to explain it a little bit better.